# How do I handle apache2 modsecurity2 warnings like Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security, mod-pagespeed

After upgrade from squeeze to wheezy I get loads of these messages in my apache errorlog when I open a webpage on myserver, (changed to `myserver.de` here):

```
[Sat Oct 19 01:06:21 2013] [error] [client 213.239.220.106] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity2/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "41"] [id "960015"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER"] [hostname "www.myserver.de"] [uri "/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom_myserver/css/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_ff7519_256x240.png"] [unique_id "UmG@7X8AAQEAAHHDMOkAAAAB"]
[Sat Oct 19 01:06:21 2013] [error] [client 213.239.220.106] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity2/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "41"] [id "960015"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER"] [hostname "www.myserver.de"] [uri "/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom_myserver/css/custom-theme/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_20_372806_1x100.png"] [unique_id "UmG@7X8AAQEAADSz0KYAAAAC"]
[Sat Oct 19 01:06:21 2013] [error] [client 213.239.220.106] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity2/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "41"] [id "960015"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER"] [hostname "www.myserver.de"] [uri "/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom_myserver/css/custom-theme/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ddd4b0_40x100.png"] [unique_id "UmG@7X8AAQEAADTD27sAAAAF"]
```

line 40 and 41 in my

```
/etc/apache2/modsecurity2/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf`:
```

look like this:

```
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "@eq 0" \
    "chain,phase:2,skip:1,t:none,log,auditlog,msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header', severity:'2',id:'960015',tag:'PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER'"
```

could this be a conflict with mod_pagespeed?

---

Update: I disabled mod_security until this issue is solved and the warnings are gone (as expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally, as a **workaround** I created a cronjob that deletes the `modsec_audit.log` which gets huge also  every hour:

```
# empty mad modsec log
16 * * * * echo "">/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
```